# in PHP How to download the file from its file path?

Tags: php, apache

I am new to PHP and trying my hands into it. I am creating a file and writing back to it. Creating a file in some path and writing to it, works fine for me. But when i try to download the same file from the same path, its not getting downloaded instead I'm getting empty file.

```
    header('Content-type: text/xml');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".'check.xml');
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize('./download/'.$_SESSION['user_name'].'/check.xml'));
    readfile('download/'.$_SESSION['user_name'].'/check.xml');
            exit;
```

Hi, Thanks for everyone. **But I saw very unusual thing. When i downloaded the file, I didn't got the full file.**

Why this case

Comment: Are you sure the filepath is correct? ./download would be a directory called download on the root of the server.

Comment: Where this file exits and the download folder exits are in same level and are in same directory. Isn't it then correct?

Comment: I posted an answer reflecting this, hope it helps :)

Comment: have you tried [file_get_contents](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents)? Probably the easiest way for beginners.

Comment: `./` only means root `/` if the PHP file is running in that dir.  `./` is the current directory of the running script.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `./` from the start of the filepath, like follows:

```
header('Content-type: text/xml');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".'check.xml');
header("Content-Length: " . filesize('download/'.$_SESSION['user_name'].'/check.xml'));
readfile('download/'.$_SESSION['user_name'].'/check.xml');
exit;
```

With Linux file systems, `./` means the root, so that's the equivalent of `/` and `../` means the directory above the current directory. It's best to use absolute file paths, but simply removing the `./` should suffice.

Comment: Excellent, and you're welcome, don't forget to mark as the chosen answer :) also, thanks Fred for making that more readable.

Comment: Hi ollieared, the downloaded file is not containing the complete text as the one I am creating it :-|

Comment: Try remove the Content-Length header, it shouldn't really be required, as the browser will automatically determine this.

Comment: No its not solving the problem still.

Comment: The problem may be with the writing of the file, have you confirmed that the file is full? Ie, by downloading it another way?

Comment: yes i opened the file which i am creating. It got created properly. But trying to download the same gives the problem.

Comment: Try the example mentioned in the answer below, which by the looks of it, is lifted from the example at php.net http://php.net/readfile

Comment: It sounds like the file isn't being created properly, other than that I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to flush the write buffers of PHP using [flush()](http://php.net/flush)

[Here](http://w-shadow.com/blog/2007/08/12/how-to-force-file-download-with-php/) is a good working function to download a file

Here is a version adapted from that page:

```
public static function downloadFile($fileName) {
    $filePath = $fileName;
    $size = filesize($filePath);

    // Taken from http://w-shadow.com/blog/2007/08/12/how-to-force-file-download-with-php/
    header("Content-type: text/plain");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$fileName\"");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
    // The three lines below basically make the download non-cacheable
    header("Cache-control: private");
    header("Pragma: private");
    header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
    header("Content-Length: " . $size);

    if ($file = fopen($filePath, "r")) {
        $buffer = fread($file, $size);  // this only works for small files!
        print $buffer;
        flush();
        fclose($file);
    }
}
```